# How to use parameters in one function in another using Javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, gruntjs, protractor, cucumber

I am performing automation using Protractor and Cucumber. I have a scenario where I need to use a output of function A in function B. In the normal way without using cucumber I was able to extend the function using `then`. But using cucumber I unable to do this.

Can someone please suggest how to do this using cucumber.

**Function A**

```
Then('abc', function (done) {
  search.cityCountyDropDown.click();
  search.cityCounty.count().then(function(count) {
    search.cityCountyCount = count;
    search.randomCityCountyIndex = (
      1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (search.cityCountyCount - 1))
    );
  })
  .then(function() {
    search
      .cityCounty
      .get(search.randomCityCountyIndex)
      .getText()
      .then(function(cityCountyLabel) {
        search.selectCityCountyLabel(cityCountyLabel);
        console.log(cityCountyLabel);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

**Function B**

```
Then('defij', function (done) {
  console.log(cityCountyLabel);
  done();
});
```

I wanted to use `cityCountyLabel` in Function B

Here is my pageObject.js file.

```
var SearchPage = function () {
    this.Category = element(by.css('[href="/abc/"]'));
    this.Header = element(by.id('abc'));

    this.cityCountyDropDown = element(by.id('abc'));
    this.cityCounty = element.all(by.xpath("//*[@id='abc']/dd/ul/li"));

    this.cityCountyCount;
    this.randomCityCountyIndex;

    this.selectCityCountyLabel = function (cityCountyLabel) {
        element(by.xpath(".//*[@id='abc']/dd/ul/li[text()='" + cityCountyLabel + "']")).click();
    };


    this.submitButton = element(by.css('input.btn-search'));
    this.searchResults = element.all(by.xpath("//*[@id='abc']/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[@class='abc']"));

    this.searchResultsCount;
    this.randomSearchResultsIndex;

    this.randomSearchResult = function (randomSearchResultsIndex, searchResult) {
        return element(by.xpath(".//*[@id='abc']/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[@class='abc'][" + randomSearchResultsIndex + "]/div[1]/h2/a"));
    }

    this.addressRegex;
}

module.exports = new SearchPage();
```

Answer (score 0):

In cucumber you pass data between steps using [World](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/world.md), which is available as `this` in the steps. Example code:

```
Then('abc', function (done) {
     this["cityCountyLabel"] = "data";
     done();
});

Then('defij', function (done) {
     // this will print out: "data"
     console.log(this["cityCountyLabel"]);
     done();
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Tomas, In my case, the `cityCountyLabel` always generates a random value. Can you please suggest me how can I use in such condition.  Can I use in this format                                   
 `Then('abc', function (done) {
     this["cityCountyLabel"] ;
     done();
});`

Comment: you use `this["cityCountyLabel"]` the same way like you would use `cityCountyLabel` variable in your example

Comment: So I can use in the above format as I mention.. else if you can please provide me with an example.

Comment: tried example you have provided but it returns undefined.